# julia JuMP with v0.7

Tags: julia, julia-jump

I tried building JuMP after compiling v0.7 but am getting errors:

```
ERROR: LoadError: Failed to precompile ReverseDiffSparse to /Users/MYUSER/.julia/lib/v0.7/ReverseDiffSparse.ji.
Stacktrace:
 [1] error at ./error.jl:33 [inlined]
 [2] compilecache(::Base.PkgId) at ./loading.jl:1208
 [3] _require(::Base.PkgId) at ./loading.jl:974
 [4] require(::Module, ::Symbol) at ./loading.jl:874
 [5] include at ./boot.jl:295 [inlined]
 [6] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1067
 [7] include(::Module, ::String) at ./sysimg.jl:26
 [8] top-level scope
 [9] eval at ./boot.jl:298 [inlined]
 [10] top-level scope at ./<missing>:3
in expression starting at /Users/MYUSER/.julia/v0.7/JuMP/src/JuMP.jl:21
ERROR: Failed to precompile JuMP to /Users/MYUSER/.julia/lib/v0.7/JuMP.ji.
Stacktrace:
 [1] error at ./error.jl:33 [inlined]
 [2] compilecache(::Base.PkgId) at ./loading.jl:1208
 [3] _require(::Base.PkgId) at ./loading.jl:1003
 [4] require(::Module, ::Symbol) at ./loading.jl:874
```

How do I interpret these / how can I build JuMP for the latest version 0.7?

Comment: There is a warning to [not expect packages to work with unreleased versions of Julia](https://julialang.org/downloads/nightlies.html). As of the time of this post, Julia v0.7 is not released. Not even the alpha of Julia v0.7 has been released: right now it's really just for the language and compiler developers. Thus you shouldn't expect JuMP to have been updated yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the original error message you'll probably see that StaticArrays (one of JuMP's indirect dependencies) does not load on 0.7. Anyway Julia 0.7 is in a pre-alpha state; there are no tagged *pre*releases of it yet as of today. It has lots of cool features, but I'd only recommend using it at this point if you're comfortable fixing broken packages and deprecation warnings.